# How do you manage personal GPS data? (what software solutions)

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, geocaching

I'm interested in creating a personal library of locations which are important to me, sort of like a personal geocache. Maybe spots I've found that I like to swim, or places with good views of the sunset, or places where something significant to me happened. Random things, which I want to be able to keep map reference to in the long term.

I can't figure out the best software approach for this, or understand what's possible and why. Here's some of the requirements:

- A phone app (I'm on iPhone) which lets me easily place a marker/record a coordinate when I am somewhere or hear about somewhere. Being able to add it to a specific list/tag it and add descriptions is necessary. If there were some way to link photos that would be cool.

  - *I currently use Maps.me, so maybe that?*.
- A way to move the GPS coordinates recorded on my phone to my computer easily.
- They should be stored in a way which lets me use version control like git to back up and watch the database grow.
- A way to view and improving the database on the desktop. Preferably overlaid with a useful map like OpenStreetMap, or better yet a topographical map or even ex OS Maps in the UK.
- An easy pathway to return the improved database to a phone-based mapping software, updating the previous versions of that database I had there. Extra points if it looks good and is on a mapping app I might want to use anyway, like Maps.me or Google Maps.
- Robust in the very long term, so not a proprietary software data type. Open sources is best, and critical data being saved in a text-like file.

It seems like KML files being imported to and from Maps.me might be a basic solution, but I haven't figured out how to edit/understand these files on a computer, and then put them back on the phone easily, especially if there are many separate lists. Is there an elegant solution, maybe that geocachers like to use? Or should I be going about this another way

Comment: GPS Exchange format (GPX) is designed for this, see https://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp  and https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] exists for software recommendation. In GIS SE we use a Focused question/Best answer model, and often close discussion-oriented *opinion-based* questions.